# WSO2 API Manager Cluster Setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying WSO2 API Manager for API Management.  I am trying a setup where I need to have 1 API Manager(KeyManager,Publisher and Store) and 2 API Gateways. Looking at the doc, I couldnt find any reference for the same. Could someone please help me on how to set the same ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. But recommended to have a separate key manager as well. For your pattern, just follow the normal guide [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0) and point to gateway cluster where mentioned in api-manager.xml from common node. Idea is to connect each other so that they can call the urls when needed.

Since KeyManager,Publisher and Store are in same node, you can leave the default urls for them in that common node. In addition, you have to configure "APIKeyValidator" url in Gateway nodes since it is separate. Do all other configurations as instructed.

Comment: Thanks Lahiru.. I shall try and provide you an update.